# Java: Rounding integer based on last digit

Tags: java

I want to round an `Integer` number based on it's last digit if it's equal, lower or higher than 5 example:
`for 315 I want to display 315`
`for 314 I want to display 310`
`for 316 I want to display 320`
How can I do this ?

Comment: and where are your **efforts** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
long val;
if (yourInteger % 5 == 0) {
    val = yourInteger;
} else
    val = 10L * Math.round((yourInteger / 10.0));
```

and **val** is a number you want to process later of course

Answer (score 2):

If You want to handle it by your self can use something like method:

```
public  int round(int a)
{
    int lastDidigt=a%10;

    if( lastDidigt==0 || lastDidigt==5)
        return a;
    if (lastDidigt <5 ) 
        return a-lastDidigt;

    return a+(10-lastDidigt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ApacheCommons](https://commons.apache.org/) [`MathUtil.round()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/util/MathUtils.html#round(double,%20int,%20int)) combined with [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_DOWN) rounding constants

> Round the given value to the specified number of decimal places. The value is rounded using the given method which is any method defined in `BigDecimal`.

This should work

```
int number = 315;
MathUtils.round((double) number, -1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```